# Get current Rendered width of Grid column Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Grid` that has some column defined and Column width is also defined in `xaml`.

```
<Border Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#001732"
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ParentContainer}">
    <Grid Name="DataGrid" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ParentContainer}"
          Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">

                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

now if i change the size of window the column width changes automatically. and i am trying to get the changed latest width with this code.

```
public void CoulmnWidthSetter()
{
    _columnWidth = DataGrid.ColumnDefinitions[4].Width.Value;
    foreach (var col in DataGrid.ColumnDefinitions)
    {

        _totalColumnsWidth = _totalColumnsWidth + col.Width.Value;
    }
}
```

and calling the Column width setter method in below Event.

```
private void ParentContainer_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoulmnWidthSetter();
    }
```

or i have tried to call this method in Window size changed event also. But still it always give me that hard coded `50` width value why ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the width? Just asking because maybe there is a more elegant solution for the "real problem".

Comment: @MightyBadaboom  i am adding a UserControl in Grid. the UserControl starts from startColumnIndex and it expand till last columnIndex . so basically i am trying to get the width between two columns. Column A and b so A+B = C and C will be the width of that UserControl that i am adding on Run time

Comment: Why not putting the `UserControl` in the same `Grid` in another `Row` with using `ColumnSpan`? Then the sizeing would be done automatically

Comment: @MightyBadaboom i think you didnt get what i am tryna do here ! i give a columnStart Index on runtime and another ColumnEnd index now if column A and Column B are then A+B would be their total width. put userControl in Start Column index increase its Span and set it;s width that i just calculated which is C

Comment: If you have a start and end column, just set `Grid.SetColumnSpan(element, endIndex - startIndex + 1);`

Comment: @Clemens hi sir ! thanks for coming to my question ! actually what i want is to get changed Column width when the window size changed the column render again and chnanges the width ! now i just want to get this updated width !

Answer (score 2):

**In WPF `Width` and `ActualWidth` are two different things.**

**What you're looking for here is the `ActualWidth` of your `ColumnDefinition`s.**

**The `ActualWidth` is a `double` value that represents that length at that moment in time.**

Signature:

```
public double ActualWidth { get; }
```

The `Width` is a `GridLength` type; that can be set by various means; including hard coded values, Star values, or Auto.  You set the `Width` (a `GridLength` type) to give the `ColumnDefinition` the information needed to dynamically adjust itself accordingly or to remain constant.  It is not intended to provide you with the current value but instead give the owner an expressive way of setting it's values.

Examples:

```
columnDefinition.Width = new GridLength(50); //Hard coded to 50

columnDefinition.Width = new GridLength(50, GridUnitType.Star); //dividend of remaining space allocated at 50.
//In other words; any other Star values will be divided in Width based on the remaining Grid size and the Star value given.
//A star value of 25* in another ColumnDefinition will make it half the length of the 50* and a value of 100* will make it twice the 50* or the 50* half of the 100*.
//Either way you look at it; the total remaining Width of the space provided by the panel gets divided out to the Star Columns and the dividend they get is based on their portion of the Star.  50* for all Columns will make them all equal.

columnDefinition.Width = GridLength.Auto; //Adjusts to the needed width dynamically.  As your content grows so does the Width.
```

`Width` is also a `DependencyProperty` so it allows `Binding` and must be set on the UI thread.

Also; just a suggestion:  You shouldn't need to set the size that way just because your view is dynamically changing size.  This is what the * star is for in the value setting.  There are also other means of doing this built in but without knowing exactly why you're doing it; have at it.

Comment: problem is not setting the width ! problem was when i hard coded the column width like this `50*` in `xaml`. then if the UI size changed the `Column` width also changes automatically. Now i wanted to get this changed new `Rendered width` of column ! that when i tried was giving the same Hardcoded value does'nt matter if i use `ActualWidth` or just `Width.Value`.

Comment: I resolved the problem by setting Every Column width on backend code. so the parent containe'r that resizes it's width divided by total columns like `OneColumnWidth = parentContainer.width/total columns` and doing this calculations everytime in ParentContainer Size changed event :)

Comment: ActualWidth should give you the new ActualWidth

Comment: This is what 1* width does.  There's no need for you to manage it that way.